# Converting OpenStreetMap.org protocolbuffer files into GDF 3.0 files using FME Desktop

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm, trying to convert .osm.pbf files into GDF 3.0 files.
I really need the GDF files because my tooling cannot accept anything else.
I've contacted Safe because I wasn't getting an GDF file output, but I was getting output in Data Inspector.

I'm reading from Luxembourg, Belgium and the Netherlands (combined into one osm.pbf file, with loads of features filtered out)

I'm using FME Desktop 2018.1, 2019 and up don't have the GDF reader/writer enabled.

My workflow, together with an example from Safe can be found here:
https://workupload.com/archive/uvemXq8b

Regarding the example, I did find a [tool](https://www.routeware.dk/download/osm2routeware_118.exe) that is able to convert OSM (non protobuffer) files into MIF/MID files.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you hear back from anyone at Safe? The OSM reading part will be easy (which is why you can see the results in the Data Inspector) but GDF writing is much more complex.

FME can't generate a workspace automatically because there's no way of telling what source information should map to which destination fields or what topological relationships to create. So you have to manually define all of that in your workspace. You can see from that example workspace just how complex that can be.

So it's possible to use that example as a template to get started, but you will have a lot of work to do. Or you could find an FME expert/partner who could help you. But basically, I think your question is beyond what anyone here can help with.

If you need an alternative, well you could use FME to convert the data to virtually any other format (like MIF/MID) and there may be another tool to convert that to GDF. But I don't see any and - as you noted - the GDF format is deprecated in FME since 2020. I think it's just not that popular a format to have that many resources devoted to it.

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thanks for the unfortunate, but expectable answer
By any chance, do you know anybody who is willing to help me?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I couldn't be much help. You can try the forums on community.safe.com and maybe the list of partners here: https://www.safe.com/partners/ - I don't know anyone specifically who's a GDF specialist, but there is a lot of mad FME skills out there.